# Reading very large external data into a Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Python library that downloads a large table (>100GB) through HTTP API. It pulls the data one row at a time and provides me an iterator of rows. So it does not consume much RAM.

I've tried to create a DataFrame by calling `spark.createDataFrame(get_row_interator())` but it causes Spark job to fail with out-of-memory error. So I guess that it tries to load all data into DataFrame on the driver node, and it runs out of memory.

Is there some other API or approach that I should use to create a DataFrame from a very large iterator that loads data from an external system?

Comment: I had a similar issue and to solve it first I save all the data in chunks in a temporary path (like a staging layer) and after downloading it, I read as Spark DataFrame and did my process to move to a raw layer